# When is my next patent maintenance fee due?

Tags: maintenance-fee

How can I lookup the next patent maintenance fee due on a patent? For example, I need to know when the fee is due for number 7833190.  Where do I look?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about one specific patent with no value for anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this out on the [US Public Pair site](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). According to Pair, your next fee first day to pay date is 11/16/2021. The surcharge date is 05/17/2022 and your last day to pay date is 11/16/2022.